# Running zio.dev Hello, world! yields error

Tags: scala, sbt, zio

Trying to simply run the "Hello, world!" example from https://zio.dev/guides/quickstarts/hello-world

Tried installing both via homebrew directly and via coursier.

Both yields:

```
zio-quickstart-hello-world % sbt run
[info] welcome to sbt 1.8.2 (Azul Systems, Inc. Java 1.8.0_322)
[info] loading project definition from /Users/syb/Documents/Temp/zio-quickstarts/zio-quickstart-hello-world/project
/Users/syb/Documents/Temp/zio-quickstarts/zio-quickstart-hello-world/build.sbt:3: error: not found: value stdSettings
    .settings(stdSettings())
              ^
/Users/syb/Documents/Temp/zio-quickstarts/zio-quickstart-hello-world/build.sbt:4: error: not found: value enableZIO
    .settings(enableZIO())
              ^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

I can press "l" and get a more verbose error and stack trace.

However I would guess that this is some common newbie thing. Found squat diddly when trying to google it though.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: looks like you are not the only one. There is an open issue [error when "sbt run"](https://github.com/zio/zio-quickstarts/issues/32) in the [zio-quickstarts](https://github.com/zio/zio-quickstarts) repo. Feel free to comment there adding as much context as you can, like your jdk version, sbt version, operative system and else.

Comment: @GastónSchabas . Added my environment info which is very different to the original posters but we get the exact same issue. Hopefully it helps eliminating some error paths.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the [issue](https://github.com/zio/zio-quickstarts/issues/32) I mentioned in the comments, if you just want to try a hello world in [ZIO](https://zio.dev/). You only need a `build.sbt` with `zio` as dependency and the same scala code showed in the repo.

- `build.sbt`

```scala
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "dev.zio" %% "zio" % "2.0.13"
)
```

- `AppMain.scala`

```scala
package dev.zio.quickstart

import zio._

object AppMain extends ZIOAppDefault {
  def run = Console.printLine("Hello, World!")
}
```

then you run the code with:

```bash
sbt run
```

and you would be able to see something like

```bash
[info] running dev.zio.quickstart.AppMain 
Hello, World!
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed May 30, 2023, 3:15:56 PM
```

Comment: Worked by just replacing `build.sbt` with you suggestion.
Still curious about what is going on with the errors. Seems like something that should auto load for a simple example isn't. That worries me a bit for taking on a larger thing. Knowing my setup is a bit broken before even starting

Comment: Not sure why this is happening to something that should help people to start using the library. It's weird. The community is pretty active and there are tons of [zio projects](https://zio.dev/ecosystem/) actively maintained. They also have a [discord channel](https://discord.gg/2ccFBr4)

Comment: backing to your question, it was about how to make a zio hello world. If you think the answer is good enough, feel free to mark it as the solution

Answer (score 0):

The errors comes from the fact they commented out a common sbt plugin library [here](https://github.com/zio/zio-quickstarts/blob/master/project/plugins.sbt#L3) I think, yet they still use it in their build definition. More precisely the methods `enableZIO()` and `stdSettings()` actually come from a ZIO SBT plugin from a repository called [zio-sbt](https://github.com/zio/zio-sbt), and it's enabled in the [root build.sbt](https://github.com/zio/zio-quickstarts/blob/master/build.sbt#L1). Probably an oversight or something, because I doubt the build actually works.